# Interval of Convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n4^n}{n^2+1}x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve the interval of convergence for the following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n4^n}{n^2+1}x^{2n}$$

Using the ratio test I'm seeing that the interval is $-\frac{1}{2} \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$. I'm struggling with evaluating the endpoints, as our lecturer stated that the series at both $x=\frac{-1}{2}$ and at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is the same as $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ which I don't quite understand. He ended up taking the integral test to then evaluate the endpoints. I would really appreciate someone explaining how we can evaluate these endpoints, as I'm very confused to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=\pm\frac12$, $\require{cancel}x^{2n}=\left(\pm\frac12\right)^{2n}=\frac1{4^n}$. Therefore, for each such $x$,\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n4^n}{n^2+1}x^{2n}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n\cancel{4^n}}{n^2+1}\times\frac1{\cancel{4^n}}\right)\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n^2+1}.\end{align}And\begin{align}\int_1^\infty\frac x{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx&=\frac12\lim_{M\to\infty}\left(\log(M^2+1)-\log(2)\right)\\&=\infty,\end{align}and therefore, by the integral test, your series diverges.